# Spark streaming deduplication

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

My goal here is deduplicate a dataframe with two columns: 'id', 'ts'. I need the max of these rows :

```
id, ts
1, "2019-02-21 08:00:00.0"
1, "2019-02-22 08:00:00.0"
2, "2019-02-22 08:00:00.0"
2, "2019-02-21 08:00:00.0"
3, "2019-02-22 08:00:00.0"
3, "2019-02-22 08:00:00.0"
```

Result should be:

```
id, ts
1, "2019-02-22 08:00:00.0"
2, "2019-02-22 08:00:00.0"
3, "2019-02-22 08:00:00.0"
```

Deduplication is needed only in this batch, then I will update a delta table with my last rows. But my streaming job launch an error indicating:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Append output mode not supported when there are streaming aggregations on streaming DataFrames/DataSets without watermark
```

Then it must have an watermark over each aggregation but I added this mark in all transformations:

```
def deduplicate(df: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
  val watermarkTime = "10 minutes"

  val dfWhatermarked = df.withWatermark("ts", watermarkTime)

  val tmpDf = dfWhatermarked
    .groupBy("id")
    .agg(max(col("ts")).as("ts"))

  val joinedDf = dfWhatermarked
    .join(
      tmpDf.withWatermark("ts", watermarkTime),
      Seq("id", "ts")
    )

  // resolves multiple rows with same 'ts'
  joinedDf
    .withWatermark("id", watermarkTime)
    .dropDuplicates(Seq("ts", "id"))
}
```

this error continues showing in the execution. Why??

Comment: I don't see your writeStream code here, what's your write mode? Append is not supported as the error message suggested.